# Linq query with three collections

Tags: c#, linq

I need to query 3 collections then return a collection to display. With my code shown here, I've created the join and want a collection of `CredentialingRequestStatus` - but I'm not getting that...

What am I doing wrong? Perhaps a `.Where()` clause?

```
var query = from cr in credentialingRequests
            join co in companyCol on cr.CompanyID equals co.ID
            join coi in coidCol on co.ID equals coi.ID
            select new CredentialingRequestStatus
                       {
                           ID = cr.ID,
                           CompanyId = cr.CompanyID,
                           COID = coi.Value,
                           FacilityName = co.Name,
                           StatusId = cr.StatusID,
                           RejectionReason = cr.RejectionReason,
                           RejectionNote = cr.RejectionNote,
                           CreatedDate = cr.CreatedDate
                       };
```

Comment: You get back an IQueryable<CredentialingRequestStatus>. Perhaps you only need a .ToList()? It doesn't look wrong otherwise. What do you get back?

Comment: Chriz, I do that when I return the collection like: return query.ToList();

Comment: Are you querying a database or memory collections? What is the input data? What is the result? what result did you expect?

Comment: I'm querying 3 collections that populate after 3 api calls to fill each collection. I expect a new collection which is a few columns from each of the 3 collections. It's all relatable flat data that joins on ID

Comment: Is this the correct fields to join on? ````join coi in coidCol on co.ID equals coi.ID````

Comment: *I'm not getting what I expect which is a collection of CredentialingRequestStatus* -- So what *do* you get? If you do `ToList()` it can't possibly be anything else. Or do you mean it's an *empty* collection? But there's also a lot we don't, but should, know. Is this Entity Framework (and which version) or another ORM? Why do you join these other tables?

Comment: Yes credentialingRequests contain CompanId which maps to Id in the company column and that Id maps to the id coid collection which is just more company data. All three collections come from 3 different API calls. All 3 have the expected data.

Comment: Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: Thanks for that, but I think we're still a little unclear as to what you are actually getting, and what you expect. For example, when I set this up locally, the query type =
`{System.Linq.Enumerable.<JoinIterator>d__122<<>f__AnonymousType0<CredentialingRequests, CompanyCol>, CoidCol, int, CredentialingRequestStatus>}`


When I do a `.ToList` on this, it becomes a

`System.Collections.Generic.List<CredentialingRequestStatus>`

This looks fine to me, but you might be see something different. If you can elaborate more on what you are actually seeing, then we might be able to help more :-)

Comment: {System.Linq.Enumerable.<JoinIterator>d__122<<>f__AnonymousType2 <CredentialingRequestResponse, CompanyResponse>, CoidCompanyIdRequestResponse, int, CredentialingRequestStatus>}

Comment: Do all of your collections have data, and have IDs that are matching correctly, and satisfy the join criteria. You could update the question with a data sample.

Comment: James, yes each collection has data that should map off companyId/Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments on question itself, the only logical conculsion is that there are no data rows that satify the join criteria.

I have successfully executed your code with the following collections populated, and have a populated result set with a single item.

Can I suggest you paste this into your soltion to test and see if it yields the same single result as me:

```
List<CredentialingRequestResponse> credentialingRequests = new List<CredentialingRequestResponse>
{
    new CredentialingRequestResponse { ID = 1, CompanyID = 1, StatusID = 1, RejectionReason = 1, RejectionNote = 1, CreatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1) }
};

List<CompanyResponse> companyCol = new List<CompanyResponse> 
{ 
    new CompanyResponse { ID = 1, Name = "Company 1" } 
};

List<CoidCompanyIdRequestResponse> coidCol = new List<CoidCompanyIdRequestResponse> 
{ 
    new CoidCompanyIdRequestResponse { ID = 1, Value = 1 } 
};
```

(Of course, your data types might be different, so you will have adjust accordingly)

Comment: James, the query works using your method of populating the collections. That is interesting. The collections are also populated when pulling from the API as well.

Comment: Does your data have keys on which the joins will work? Is it possible that you are getting no results, because that is the correct result for the data set. Put another way, an you see 3 rows (one from each table) that you expect to join and return a result set? If so can you amend the original question to contain this data?

Comment: I believe it is just a join issue, If I take out the join on the coidCol, then I get the expected.

Comment: Confirmed. the API for the coidCol, is not returning the expected Id. a change in my process for obtaining the correct id and it is now returning the correct results. Thank you!